# Rails 5 - Namespacing models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces

I am using namespacing in my Rails 5 app to try to keep resources organised.

I've been generating resources using the command line by adding the namespace folder to the generate command.

This makes a folder in the models folder for the main folder which the namespaced files are saved in.

I've since been reading posts from others that suggest namespacing models is not a good idea.

An example of what I currently have is:

```
class Stance::Assessment < ApplicationRecord
```

It seems to work alright so far.

What is the problem with namespacing models?

If it is a problem, does that mean I can't organise my models into folder groups, or does it mean that the model class doesnt need to be named wiht the "Stance::"?

Comment: Can you link those posts bashing namespaced models? I can't find a compelling argument against it if you're following the conventions. Group the files inside a folder named `stance`, prepend the class with `Stance` or use modules(which I prefer).

Comment: @AlexandreAngelim https://dhampik.com/blog/rails-admin-scaffold

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a certain cost of complexity involved with "namespacing" your models. Ruby does not actually have true namespaces. Rather it has has modules which provide encapsulation.

Rails and ActiveRecord was designed around placing your application code in the `Main` object (the global object). While this might seem like a bad practice it is very simple and works well with the convention over configuration approach. It also allows a much simpler autoloading scheme and avoids the need to nest every single file in an additional folder.

Namespacing does have great organizational merits though and lets you avoid collisions. But there are a few minor aches in the backside:

- table prefixes, having the generated table names like `my_app_projects_tasks` is really inconvenient when you need to write a custom join.
- You need to override `ActiveModel::Naming` so that it does not look for paths like `my_app_projects_tasks_path` when using the polymorphic route helpers.
- You need to explicitly set the `class_name` option when creating associations or override how ActiveRecord resolves constant names.

Comment: can you give me a steer on the polymorphic route helper point? I'm trying to figure this out now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40518887/rails-5-using-polymorphic-associations-rendering-the-views

Comment: Seems odd that Rails doesn't seem to easily handle this right out the box. I'd have thought that a large app like Github might have required it.

Comment: @BenKoshy its a game of tradeoffs. Rails is really geared towards simple applications and rapid prototyping. Its very much possible to nest your models in Rails and customize the generators however you want though without a huge amount of effort.

Answer (score 1):

you can prefix your models, so instead of `Stance::Assessment` you would have `StanceAssessment`. not as clean as a namespace but it's pretty close to it